# Calculating trajectories from bounding box

Tags: python, math, computer-vision, physics

I'm detecting vehicles from a video file, and then I get a bounding box, x,y coordinates.

I'm planning to calculate the trajectory of the vehicle.

So I have the X,Y of the bounding box, I will calculate tan(theta) Y/X for every frame.
Then calculate the velocity = 
with initial velocity

```
  x = ((v*k)*np.cos(i)) # get positions at every point in time
  y = ((v*k)*np.sin(i))-((0.5*g)*(k**2))
```

My problem how can I calculate the time K in each frame ? how to predict it ?

Comment: `t = number_of_cadr/cadr_frequency` ?

Comment: what is cadr, ? can you explain and write an answer ?

Comment: cadr it's frame. t = frame_index / fps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frames in video go with equal intervals. Usually you can get framerate property (FPS: frames per second) for given video (typical values of FPS are 25 or 30).

So there are FPS frames in one second, and time interval between them is 1/FPS.

To calculate time difference between frame index a and frame index b:

```
t = (b - a) / FPS
```

Comment: so I just calculate frame++/ FPS ?

Comment: Yes, if zero time corresponds to zero-th frame